# Function Types as Return Types In Swift Explanation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working my way through the Swift Programming Manual from Apple and there is this example in the book using Function Types as Return Types.

```
// Using a function type as the return type of another function
func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int {
    return input + 1
}
func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int {
    return input - 1
}
func chooseStepFunction(backwards:Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}

var currentValue = 3
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(currentValue > 0)

println("Counting to zero:")
// Counting to zero:
while currentValue != 0 {
    println("\(currentValue)...")
    currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)
}
println("zero!")
```

From my understanding this

```
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(currentValue > 0)
```

calls `chooseStepFunction` and passes "true" because 3 > 0.  Also I understand how the following is evaluated:

```
return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
```

My question is how does the function `stepBackward` know to use `currentValue` as its input parameter?  I see what is happening but I don't understand the how or why it's happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stepBackward` function doesn't know to use `currentValue` in this line -- it's not called at all at this point:

```
return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
```

Instead, a reference to the `stepBackward` is returned from `chooseStepFunction` and assigned to `moveNearerToZero`. `moveNearerToZero` is essentially now another name for the `stepBackward` function that you defined earlier, so when this happens in your loop:

```
currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)
```

you are actually calling `stepBackward` with `currentValue` as the parameter.

To see this in action, add this line right after you create `moveNearerToZero`:

```
println(moveNearerToZero(10))     // prints 9, since 10 is passed to stepBackward
```

Comment: Ok I see now.  Thank you.  This exercise put my brain in an 'endless loop'.In my limited experience I have trouble wrapping my head around where something like this would be useful.  From a readability standpoint it seems a little complicated.  Is this a common practice?

Comment: It probably doesn't happen very often in the way shown in this example, where you're passing back one or another existing function. It can be *very* useful when passing back a closure, which encapsulates the values from the context around it. I think that's your next chapter. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `chooseStepFunction(backwards:Bool) -> (Int) -> Int` is returning a (function that returns int).  In this way, when `chooseStepFunction` is executed, the function returns the actual function that should be called based on the criteria and assigns it to moveNearerToZero.  This allow it to call the correct function based on `currentValue` later in the code.

In the first iteration, the `currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)` is essentially calling `currentValue = stepBackward(currentValue)`.

From the apple developer library:

"You can use a function type as the return type of another function. You do this by writing a complete function type immediately after the return arrow (->) of the returning function."