# Swift - Function Types as Return Types

Tags: swift, function, return

I'm trying to wrap my head around "Functions Types as Return Types ([Swift Doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html))". I noticed that there's also a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310379/function-types-as-return-types-in-swift-explanation) to this question but i'm still a bit confused.

I'm quite confused with the `-> (Int) -> Int` in `chooseStepFunction`. I see that `chooseStepFunction` is returning a function that returns an `Int` but i don't understand what that exactly means and why is the Int in () `(Int)`. Also, how would re read this '`-> (Int) -> Int`

```
func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int {
return input + 1
}

func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int {
    return input - 1
}

func chooseStepFunction(backwards:Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}

var currentValue = 3
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0)
// moveNearerToZero now refers to the stepBackward() function
```

Comment: it's inside () because its a function like you said, func chooseStepFunction(backwards:Bool) -> (Int) -> Int reads like chooseStepFunction returns function which returns Int. (Int)-> Int here you can also read as stepForward(Int)-> Int or stepBackward(Int) -> Int depending on boolean value provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it clearer let's create a type alias

```
typealias functionWithIntParameterAndIntReturnValue = (Int) -> Int
```

and change `chooseStepFunction` to

```
func chooseStepFunction(backwards:Bool) -> functionWithIntParameterAndIntReturnValue {
    return backwards ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
```

This matches exactly the signatures of both `step...` functions

```
(input: Int) -> Int
```

which have an `Int` parameter and return an `Int`. If you omit the parameter label you get

```
(Int) -> Int
```

The parentheses are a semantical requirement